# Has the Mongoose Black Diamond 2 Frame been released?

Tags: downhill

Does anyone here knows if Mongoose has already produced this frame and is out on the market?

[image: black diamond 2]

Or it was just in their drawing table and didn't produce it? Because i haven't seen this frame on their offering in their site. I like this frame because of its simplicity and beauty though I haven't ridden this bike before.

Comment: Simplicity?  Its a frame with moving parts!  Nothing there is simple!

Comment: Though seriously you'll probably get a better answer by consulting with Mongoose support people.  Try the contact links on their website.

Comment: Dear Mongoose, it's confusing when you call a frame "Black Diamond" when that frame is neither black nor a diamond. Yours,

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as a product recommendation question. It's not asking any kind of subjective question about the quality of the product or anything that could go out of date, such as availability. It's just asking if a particular product ever went to market. I suppose, technically, it could go out of date if the answer is "no" today but then they release it tomorrow. But that seems a minor concern.

Comment: We don’t have product recommendation questions as they go out of date quickly. That also applies to this question.

Comment: @RoboKaren I disagree. A product recommendation can go out of date because either the recommended product stops being available or because any better product becomes available, with the additional problems that "better" is completely subjective and that different products are available in different parts of the world. Here, the only reason the question can go out of date is if the answer is "no" today but this one specific product is released in the future. And none of the other objections apply. This question has almost nothing in common with product recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer **No** (as of 2018-02-07)

There is a mongoose Black Diamond Double in 2008 which looks like this, but the pivots are in different places.

[image: https://ep3.pinkbike.org/p3pb2429620/p3pb2429620.jpg]

Second data point is that the top google match for "mongoose black diamond 2" is this question.  So that is a good indication that it doesn't exist by that name.

Its very hard to prove the non-existence of something.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts on this. i have this kind of frame. yeah its been around that year 2008-2010 when they produced this frame i suppose. it's what they offered as Boot'r for DH and Pinn'r for Freeride. But really man...i love the black diamond 2 frame above.